# How can we connect the interface (wpf) and MS ACCess database

Tags: wpf, ms-access, wpfdatagrid

I've to do a project with Microsoft Access 'we obliged to make with this tool' 
I've implemented a user interface (bottoms and effects) using expression blend , and I build my database .The problem how can I make the relation between them.
as I read that MS can give us the new features in Access 2010, Microsoft can very well decide to go into a Workflow like direction rather than a pure 'classical' C#/VbNet direction. That would also allow a better integration with a WPF like user interface, and web solutions.

How can I make an extrenal program (my interface) , which can excute the Access Queries in Microsoft Access 2010.

Can benefet WPF features to make this .Or should I build a project with C# using VS.

Comment: Why are there so many recent questions from WPF users about connecting to Jet/ACE databases?

Answer (score 1):

WPF is a platform to build a better UI for the desktop applications. That doesn't stop you from using ADO.NET classes from a WPF application. You can always connect to Access using ADO.NET framework. Here is a link to get you started : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One of the applications I maintain is implemented partially in C# and partially in VB.NET, and some of the older portions of the database are still in Microsoft Access databases.

It is not at all difficult to to display and edit data from the Access databases in the WPF code.  In fact, the user can't really tell where the Access databases end and other database technologies begin.  Originally this was done by manually writing code to load and update Access data, but our newer code uses a small data access layer that can load objects from Access and save the changes back later.

The key is to load the Access data into objects that implement INotifyPropertyChanged, then bind them to WPF views.  When the user hits "Ok" or "Save" as the case may be, changes are detected and saved back to the Access database.

I didn't understand the part of your question about WPF versus C# and VS:  You will be using WPF, C# and Visual Studio all at the same time to build your application.